# UNION in MySQL 5.7.2

Tags: mysql, union

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

I am getting bad results by a UNION of COUNT(*).

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Piezas
  , ''Motor
from parque
where `parque`.`CausasParalizacion` = 2

UNION

SELECT
   ''Piezas
 , COUNT(*) AS Motor
from parque
where `parque`.`CausasParalizacion` = 3
```

The result should be 30 and 12, and I am getting 3330 and 3132.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The query that you have provided doesn't explain the "bad" results.. MySQL doesn't lie about the result unless the programmer is making the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think MySQL is returning a "bad" result.  The results returned by MySQL are per the specification.

Given no `GROUP BY` each of the SELECT statements will return one row. We can verify by running each SELECT statement separately.  We'd expect the UNION result of the two SELECT to be something like

```
 Piezas    Motor
 ------    -----
             mmm
    ppp
```

You say the results should be `'30'` and `'12'`

My guess is that MySQL is returning the characters '30' and '12'.

But we should be very suspicious, and note the hex representation of the ASCII encoding of those characters

```
x'30' -> '0' 
x'31' -> '1'
x'32' -> '2'
x'33' -> '3'
```

As a demonstration

```
SELECT HEX('30'), HEX('12')
```

returns

```
HEX('30')  HEX('12')
---------  ---------
3330       3132
```

---

I don't think MySQL is returning "bad" results.  I suspect that the column metadata for the columns is confusing the client.  (We do note that both of the columns is a mix of two different datatypes being UNION'd.  On one row, the datatype is string/varchar (an empty string), and the other row is integer/numeric (result of COUNT() aggregate.)

And I'm not sure what the resultset metadata for the columns ends up as.

I suspect that the issue with the client interpretation the resultset *metadata*, determining the *datatype* of the columns.  And the client is  deciding that the most appropriate way to display the values is as a hex representation of the raw bytes.

---

Personally, I would avoid returning a UNION result of different/incompatible datatypes. I'd prefer the datatypes be consistent.

If I had to do the `UNION` of incompatible datatypes, I would include an explicit conversion into compatible/appropriate datatypes.

But once I am at that point, I have to question why I need any of that rigmarole with the mismatched datatypes, why we need to return two separate rows, when we could just return a single row (probably more efficiently to boot)

```
SELECT SUM( p.`CausasParalizacion` = 2 ) AS Piezas
     , SUM( p.`CausasParalizacion` = 3 ) AS Motor
  FROM parque p
 WHERE p.`CausasParalizacion` IN (2,3)
```

---

To avoid the aggregate functions returning NULL,

we can wrap the aggregate expressions in an IFNULL (or ANSI-standard COALESCE) function..

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM( p.`CausasParalizacion` = 2 ),0) AS Piezas
     , IFNULL(SUM( p.`CausasParalizacion` = 3 ),0) AS Motor
  FROM parque p
 WHERE p.`CausasParalizacion` IN (2,3)
```

-or-

we could use a COUNT() of an expression that is either NULL or non-NULL

```
SELECT COUNT(IF( p.`CausasParalizacion` = 2 ,1,NULL) AS Piezas
     , COUNT(IF( p.`CausasParalizacion` = 3 ,1,NULL) AS Motor
  FROM parque p
 WHERE p.`CausasParalizacion` IN (2,3)
```

If, for some reason it turns out it is faster to run two separate SELECT statements, we could still combine the results into a single row. For example:

```
SELECT s.Piezas
     , t.Motor 
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Piezas
           FROM parque p
          WHERE p.`CausasParalizacion` = 2 
       ) s
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Motor
           FROM parque q
          WHERE q.`CausasParalizacion` = 3 
       ) t
```

Comment: Spencer, I think that the problem was about encoding. Ej. When I execute the consult in console, the result was the expected, however, in the phpmyadmin was the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Spencer, I think that the problem was about encoding. Ej. When I execute the consult in console, the result was the expected, the otherwise in the phpmyadmin.

However, I must say that your first solution works perfectly, Thanks a lot bro.